# Spring in action 5- chapter 3 issue

Tags: spring

I am following Spring in Action, 5th edition, and in chapter 3 I am facing this issue:

```
@PostMapping
public String processDesign(@Valid Taco design, Errors errors, @ModelAttribute Order order) {
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        return "design";
    }
    Taco saved = designRepo.save(design);
    order.addDesign(saved);

    return "redirect:/orders/current";
}
```

On `Submit your Taco` action, a request goes to the above method, but the `ingredients` field in `Taco` object is null.

My `Taco` class is the same as provided [here](https://github.com/habuma/spring-in-action-5-samples/blob/master/ch03/tacos-jdbc/src/main/java/tacos/Taco.java).

So, what am I missing?

Comment: hard to help if you don't send how you do the post

Comment: Here is the view which contains POST action:https://github.com/habuma/spring-in-action-5-samples/blob/master/ch03/tacos-jdbc/src/main/resources/templates/design.html

Answer (score 0):

Removing

```
model.addAttribute("order",new Order());
```

in `OrderController` would fix the issue. 
`TacoController` is passing the model with order instance populated, however the get method in order controller, specifically the above line add a new order to model, overwriting the old order details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate the list of ingredients in case of error (again).

```
@PostMapping
    public String designForm(@ModelAttribute("design") @Valid Taco taco, Errors errors, Model model) {
        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            List<Ingredient> ingredients = ingredientRepository.findAll();

            Type[] types = Ingredient.Type.values();
            for (Type x : types) {
                model.addAttribute(x.toString().toLowerCase(),
                         ingredients.stream().filter(p -> p.getType().equals(x)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
            }
            return "design";
        }
        log.info("Processing desing: " + taco);

        return "redirect:/order/current";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I too am going over Spring in Action 5, chapter 3. I had an issues with my "ingredients" field being null as well. I have managed to fix this.

Somewhere in Ch3, the code for "ingredients" changed types. In your Taco class, "ingredients" should be List (as seen from ch2); however this changed to List in Ch3 without any mention. I found out about that change looking at the chapter's source code. Anyhow, because the list's type switched from String to Ingredient, Spring will no longer bind the list of ingredients from the form.

My fix is this:
1 - revert the Taco class' "ingredient" field to be a List data type.
2 - in the JdbcTacoRepository class, make the following changes:
2a - add a new private final field of type IngredientRepository
2b - update the constructor to autowire the above field
2c - within the save(Taco taco) method, use the following changes:

`for(String ingredientId : taco.getIngredients()){  Ingredient ingredient = ingredientRepo.findOne(ingredientId); saveIngredientToBurger(ingredient, burgerId); }`

Overall the ingredients field was null b/c Spring couldn't bind a String object to an Ingredient object. I'm still trying to understand how Spring recognizes the ingredient in the first place, but hopefully this works for you.